# JSF - f:param: parameter not sent but jessionid and ln=javax.faces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, wildfly

I've the following facelet code here

```
<h:form>
  <h:button
    value="Open"
    outcome="foo.xhtml">
    <f:param
      name="fid"
      value="#{foo.bar}" />
  </h:button>
</h:form>
```

Usually the parameter is sent and the url of page `foo.xhtml` appears as

```
https://foo.bar/foo.xhtml?fid=4711
```

This is correct and expected. But sometimes it appears as

```
https://foo.bar/foo.xhtml;jessionid=...?ln=javax.faces
```

and the parameter is **not** sent. What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

WildFly 12 Final; Mojarra 2.3.3.SP1

**Update (09.03.2021)**

From end user report, now the same problem with:

```java
public String foo() {
    return "foo.xhtml?fid=4711&amp;faces-redirect=true";
}
```

But still only sporadically.

Comment: JSESSIONID is correct, but `ln` param is indeed wrong. Looks like to be just a bug in Mojarra. Is your problem reproducible in the currently available WildFly 22? It has the currently latest Mojarra version.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that this error occurs sporadic only. So it's not reliable reproducible. Not even in WildFly 12. As your comment says it seems to be a bug. This isn't a solution but so I'm sure that isn't a programming error of mine. In some time we will have WildFly 20. We will see...

Comment: You can just download it from wildfly.org and test local. If it works then you know that you most possibly just need to upgrade Mojarra in your old WildFly. But better is of course to upgrade WildFly itself.

Comment: We've set `enable-http2="true"` in standalone.xml configuration file and use IE 11 as webbrowser. Could be that the reason?

Comment: Nope, as said in 1st comment, it's a bug in Mojarra, the `ln` param is wrong. It's definitely set by Mojarra not by the server. The rest is completely normal.